# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation

Tags: sql, angularjs

Okay so i'm trying to add a new team into my 'teams' column on my database, however I am getting this error [QueryException","message":"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `teams` (`name`, `game`) ]

**This is the HTML -**

```
<form ng-submit="addteam()" ng-model="teamform">
            <h2>Add Team</h2>
            <label>
                Team Name 
                <input type="text" ng-model="teamform.name"/>
            </label>
            <label>
                Game
                <select ng-model="teamform.game">
                    <option ng-repeat="game in games" value="{{game.gameID}}">{{game.game_name}}</option>
                </select>
            </label>
            <input value="submit" type="submit"/>
        </form>
```

**This is the Service -**

```
addteam:function(form){
            var call = Phone.call('api/team/insert', form);
            call.success(function(data) {
                Flash.show('Team Created');
            });
            call.error(function() {
            });

            return call;
        }
```

**This is the Controller -**

```
$scope.addteam = function(){
        PanelService.addteam($scope.teamform);
    };
```

**This is the TeamController -**

```
public function insertTeam(){
        Team::insertGetId(array(
            'name'=>Input::get('name'),
            'game'=>Input::get('game')
        ));
    }
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this in your controller

```
$scope.teamform = {}
```

Comment: You're a life saver! Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, I have to wait 5 more minutes :)